# Add Woocommerce Pre-Order Tab to my custom Product type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want Woocommerce pre-order plugin to add itself to my custom product type i have created. If i choose Woocommerce standard product types i get a pre-order tab.

Is there a hook to pass in my "custom product type" to the plugin so it knows that it should be visible?

I have follow this guide: http://jeroensormani.com/adding-a-custom-woocommerce-product-type/ to actually add the custom product and it works.

I dont have a code sample because i dont know how this could be done .

> **EDIT #1** - User wanted to have reference code from the plugin .

This is taken from the "class-wc-pre-orders-admin.php"

```
 /** product hooks */

 // add 'Pre-Orders' product writepanel tab
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs', array( $this, 'add_product_tab' ), 11 );

 // Add 'Pre-Orders' tab content
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_write_panels', array( $this, 'add_product_tab_options' ), 11 );


 /** Functions **/
 <?php
 /**
 * Add 'Pre-Orders' tab to product writepanel
 *
 * @since 1.0
 */
  public function add_product_tab() {
 ?>
  <li class="wc_pre_orders_tab wc_pre_orders_options">
     <a href="#wc_pre_orders_data"><?php _e( 'Pre-Orders', WC_Pre_Orders::TEXT_DOMAIN ); ?></a>
  </li>
 <?php
}
```

Cant find where they filter the tabs, just adds it to the array that prints.

At the moment i do not have a filter on the hook "product_data_tabs"

> **EDIT #2** - Added my code .

```
/* STEP 1 */
function register_simple_custom_product_type() {

    class WC_Product_Simple_Custom_Product extends WC_Product_Simple {

        public function __construct( $product ) {

            $this->product_type = 'simple_custom';

            parent::__construct( $product );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_simple_custom_product_type' );  



/* STEP 2 */
function add_simple_custom_product( $types ){

    $types[ 'simple_custom' ] = __( 'Simple custom' );

    return $types;
}
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_simple_custom_product' );  



/* STEP 3*/
function custom_product_tabs( $tabs) {

    $tabs['custom'] = array(
        'label'     => __( 'Custom', 'woocommerce' ),
        'target'    => 'custom_options',
        'class'     => array( 'show_if_simple_custom', 'show_if_variable_custom' ),   
);
  /* filter to show pre_order tab with this product-type */
    tabs['pre_order']['class'][] = 'show_if_simple_custom show_if_variable_custom';

return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'custom_product_tabs' );
```

But this does not .

1. show a new tab with the name of Custom .
2. Show the pre-order tab when i select Simple custom as product-type in the drop-down field .

> **EDIT #3** .

Correct answer is marked and here is link to corrected code http://pastebin.com/GM1UmDwC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a hook, it's javascript, that controls what is and is not visible as you change product types. I don't have access to the pre order plugin right now, but, something along these lines should work if you find the correct class for the pre-order tab.

```
jQuery( function($){

    $( 'body' ).on( 'woocommerce-product-type-change', function( event, select_val, select ) {

        if ( select_val === 'your-product-type' ) {
             // modify to an actual CSS class selector
            $( '.some-class-selector-for-pre-order-tab' ).show();
        }

    } );

    $( 'select#product-type' ).change();

} );
```

Alternatively, it may be more efficient to add a 'show-if-PRODUCT-TYPE' (where PRODUCT-TYPE needs to be replaced with the value of your product type from the `<select>` element) class to the pre-order tab. If memory, serves, then WooCommerce will automatically show it when the product type is changed.

```
jQuery( function($){
    $( '.some-class-selector-for-pre-order-tab' ).add_class( 'show-if-YOUR-PRODUCT-TYPE' );
    $( 'select#product-type' ).change();
} );
```

**EDIT #1**

I forgot about filtering the tab classes! This is probably simpler and doesn't require any additional scripts as with the right classes, WooCommerce will handle the hide/show from it's own script automatically. You  must already be filtering this to add in your own custom tab, but at the same time you can adjust the other tabs.

Here's an example until I can see more of your code and can edit to match accordingly.

```
**
 * Add a custom product tab.
 */
function custom_product_tabs( $tabs) {

    // This is where you register your product type's tab.
    $tabs['rental'] = array(
        'label'     => __( 'Rental', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'target'    => 'rental_options',
        'class'     => array( 'show_if_simple_rental'  ),
    );

    // Add an additional class to an existing tab, ex: Inventory.
    $tabs[ 'inventory' ][ 'class' ][] = 'show_if_simple_rental';

    return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'custom_product_tabs' );
```

**Edit #2**

Because Pre Orders is adding their tab via the `woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs` action hook instead of via the `woocommerce_product_data_tabs` filter, my earlier edit won't work. Pre-Orders is then using it's own script to toggle visibility and you don't want to get into dealing with priority of scripts. Turns out that Pre-Orders has a function for getting product types that it supports and you can add your own type via its `wc_pre_orders_supported_product_types` filter:

```
function so_42253729_add_pre_order_support( $types ){
    $types[] = 'your-product-type';
    return $types;
}
add_filter( 'wc_pre_orders_supported_product_types', 'so_42253729_add_pre_order_support' );
```

Comment: Hi again, thanx for your look. I find it in the CSS of the admin page that when i choose my product type "simple_custom" this is the class of the <li> in the source-code 

'<li class="wc_pre_orders_tab wc_pre_orders_options" style="display: block;"><a href="#wc_pre_orders_data">Pre-Orders</a></li>'

when i choose the regular "simple product" it states (style="display:block"). Whit the inspector when i change that the "pre-order" tab is showing. So gonna try and change the style of the class.

Comment: Actually, I think you may be right that is a hook/filter issue and not a JS issue. Can you edit your question to show me how you are filtering `woocommerce_product_data_tabs`? (So if following the linked tutorial then it would be your `custom_product_tabs()` function). *And* please search through Pre-Orders to find how they are filtering `woocommerce_product_data_tabs` and post their function too.

Comment: NM. I found my copy of pre-orders. They are weirdly *not* filtering `woocommerce_product_data_tabs`. Apparently in an attempt to make life more difficult.

Comment: okey, but shall i delete the custom_product_tabs code then and add it via the Edit 2 filter :)

Comment: Still does not work :( 
function add_pre_orders_support_custom( $types ){  
        $types[] = 'simple_custom';
        return $types;
    } 
    add_filter( 'wc_pre_orders_supported_product_types', 'add_pre_orders_support_custom' );

Comment: [This code](http://pastebin.com/GM1UmDwC) is resulting in [this metabox](http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/2778/RNzs0R.png) so it is working for me. The `wc_pre_orders_supported_product_types` filter has been in the code for 2 years so I don't it's an out of date version issue. Please try enabling `WP_DEBUG` and making sure you don't have any errors that could be interfering.

Comment: Thank you, Marked as correct! I will edit your code to my needs and try to filter away som tabs and try to get it to a variable product.
 Do you have a link to the source of  "wc_pre_orders_supported_product_types" cuz i cant find it on the net..

Comment: You're welcome. No link, because the WooCommerce Pre Orders plugin source code isn't public. You can always search entire folders of code with an decent text editor, like Sublime Text or Notepad++.